# Is it possible to check what engine was used to produce an Android game?

Tags: android, game-hacking

I want to know what engine was used (if any) to produce an Android game, is it possible? What to look for in decompiled apk? Or maybe I have to check with a proxy for some certain http requests? Or some special files included?

Answer (score 1):

If the engine includes native components, names of files in the `lib` directory of the APK might give you some hints. E.g. `libunity.so` and `libmono.so` likely mean the game is using Unity.